# network visualization tool with collapse and expand capability for groups

Tags: data-visualization

I'm looking for a convenient free tool to visualize my network that supports hierarchy.

There are some nodes in my network that are grouped together before; I want to have groups as a hyper node and expand them to display the hidden nodes and edges. In addition My network is weighted and I want to have correct labels between the collapsed node and other nodes that has link to it's hidden sub-nodes.

I've used [Cytoscape](https://cytoscape.org/) and it's [gexf-app plug-in](http://apps.cytoscape.org/apps/gexfapp) but it shows odd edges between some hyper nodes and sub-nodes of other groups.

Also, I've tried [Gephi](https://gephi.org/) but It's not convenient for me.

Comment: Can you describe what would be convenient? What is wrong with Gephi?

Comment: I can use  Gephi 0.9.0 with openJDK 1.8 but support for hierarchical networks was removed in this version and because of java limit access I can't use the older version (Gephi0.8.2).

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I tried d3.js library. d3 has prepared example for trees (like https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130) but I needed to work with networks(graph) not just tree networks. So I wrote some javascript code using d3 to solve my problem. There is some d3 tutorials like https://www.dashingd3js.com/table-of-contents. D3 is accessible from https://d3js.org/ and from there you can see it's beautiful examples.